# SwiftUI, using ForEach inside ZStack causes screen flickering

Tags: foreach, swiftui, zstack, viewbuilder

- when calling `router1()`, there is quick (white screen) flickering
- when calling `router2()`, no flickering

NOTE: in both cases `navigationLevelsStack` just has **1 element**

It seems it just depends on the fact that `router1()` uses a `ForEach`?

Is there a way to make `ForEach` not causing that flickering?

```
@ViewBuilder func router1(_ stateProvider: StateProvider,_ events: Events) -> some View {

    ZStack {
        ForEach(navigationLevelsStack, id: \.self.URI) { screenIdentifier in
             self.screenPicker(screenIdentifier)
        }
    }

}

@ViewBuilder func router2(_ stateProvider: StateProvider,_ events: Events) -> some View {

    ZStack {
             self.screenPicker(navigationLevelsStack.last!)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling `router1()`/`router2()`?

Comment: forEach in ZStack will keep on adding screenPicker on top of each other till the loop ends, may be that might be causing it depending upon what exactly screenPicker does.

Comment: @DanieleB can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @TusharSharma this is happening even if `navigationLevelsStack` just has 1 element

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason:

It is because `self.URI` is a computed property, so each time it was called, it took time to process.

**UPDATE:**

Actually the reason is not because `.URI` is a computed property.
It has to do with the fact that the old ForEach `id` value is replaced by a new ForEach `id` value. If you want to avoid the flickering, it's ok to render a different view, but the ForEach `id` should stay the same. So, it makes sense it to be an index number.

Comment: I feel like I've seen a very, very similar answer before. Deja vu?